# Disable a site collection column inside lists's quick edit grid

Tags: 2013, list, development, javascript, client-side-rendering

I read the following link on how SharePoint 2013 supports disabling a site collection column inside the list's quick edit grid [link](http://chuvash.eu/2014/11/28/disabling-a-column-in-quick-edit/). so I tried to apply the same inside a custom list. So I wrote the following JSLink :-

```
(function () {
alert(fromhide);
    var overrideContext = {};
    overrideContext.Templates = overrideContext.Templates || {};
    overrideContext.Templates.OnPreRender = function(ctx) {
        var statusField = ctx.ListSchema.Field.filter(function(f) {
           return f.Name === 'Formate Number'
        });
        if (statusField) {
            statusField[0].AllowGridEditing = false;
        }
    }
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideContext);
})();
```

and then I associated the site column with the above js script using the following power shell command:-

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://testsite
$field = $web.Fields["Formate Number"]
$field.JSLink = "/_layouts/15/testscript.js"
$field.Update($true)
```

now when I access the list view page source inside my browser I can see that the testscript.js is being rendered , but this will not prevent editing the 'Formate Number' inside the quick edit grid ???

I am confused on why this is not working in my case?

Answer (score 0):

In the Article the Author is using the column's internal name:

```
f.Name === 'Request_x0020_Status';
```

I think if you use the internal name of the column

```
f.Name === 'Formate Number'
```

which would be I am assuming 'Formate_x0020_Number' might solve the issue.

You can get the internal name for a column by browsing to the List Settings > Edit Column and look at the QueryString. This will be url encoded. You will get similar to the following:

/_layouts/FldEdit.aspx?List=%7B37920121%2D19B2%2D4C77%2G56EE%2D8B3E08724224%7D&Field=Formate%5Fx0020%5FNumber

%5F represents '_' and the field name is 'Formate_x0020_Number'.